# Отображение точек в определенном месте

Tags: json, карты

На карте есть точки возможных пожаров. И что сделать, чтобы точки были в определенной области. С помощью редактирования JSON файла это возможно? (Карта точек обновляется)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что используете для отображения карты?

Comment: web app builder for arcgis